# How to provide parameter in vim macro

Tags: vim

Is it possible to provide some parameter when recording a macro in vim via prompt or some other ways?

Edit: 
I have such code:

```
foo
bar
```

And I would like to surround each with ruby block:

```
expect do
  foo
end.to raise_error(CustomClass)

expect do
  foo
end.to raise_error(OtherCustomClass)
```

So, it is easy to create a macro that will result with:
    expect do
      foo
    end.to raise_error()

```
expect do
  foo
end.to raise_error()
```

But it will be nice to have prompt that will be used to set raise_error method parameter. In each use of macro this parameter will be different.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information as to the problem you are trying to solve? There are many ways to achieve efficient workflow in Vim.

Comment: in some place in my macro I hit diw and I would like to place there custom text I privide.

Comment: How is this different to `ciw<some-text>^[` followed by `.`?

Comment: I have updated question a bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I agree with everyone else that if you need this feature, you're probably going about things inefficiently, it is possible to insert a variable text string into a document as part of a macro. The trick is to store the text you want to use in your macro in a register.

1. yank some text into a named register, for example `"xyw` to yank a word into the x register
2. record your macro, `qq`, when you want to place the variable text, put it, for example `"xp` to put the text in the x register into the document where the cursor is
3. now, when you play your q macro, `@q`, it will use whatever is *currently* in the x register, so you can yank different text into the x register, play your q macro, and the newly yanked text will be used.

Comment: You don't need to use any registers of any sort. Just map a key like this ```map <F2> :Ack <C-r><C-w><CR>```
and by pressing `F2` key, `<C-r><C-w>` will paste the word which is under the cursor, so in this example you will be able to Ack for a word that you currently have under the cursor.

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about recording a macro with `qx...q`, this is not possible.

However you could still do : `:let @y = substitute(@x, 'old_pattern', 'replacement', 'g')` and then use `@y`.

You could also define a function:

```
function Play(myArg)
   execute 'normal sequence_of_characters' . a:myArg . 'other_sequence_of_characters'
endfunction

call Play('foo')
```

Answer (score 2):

Very particularly in the OP's situation, where you really only have precisely *two* variable pieces of content, I find the easiest method to be a bastardisation of [@mkomitee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111533/mkomitee)'s [approach above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8137385/31897).

Instead of manually saving the two ‘parameters’ into registers before each usage of the macro, I prefer to type the “first parameter,” visual-select it, evaluate the macro, then type the “second parameter.” To achieve this, I start the macro with a deletion command (a simple <kbd>d</kbd>, assuming you're always going to invoke the macro in visual-mode, for instance); then finish it with a command that switches to insert mode (like <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>i</kbd>), and finally, while still in insert mode, a <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd> to cause the macro to also leave Vim in insert mode when it's done.

As a slightly simple example, if the two “parameters” are single words, here's the keystrokes to create (and then invoke) a macro to manipulate `widget.snog()` to a parameterised `widgetFoo.fooSnog(bar)`:

> - foo<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>qq</kbd> <kbd>"zdw</kbd> — *we're now recording to the `q` register, with the first ‘argument’ in `z`*
>
>   ```
>   ‸
>   ```
> - <kbd>"aP</kbd> — *prefix-paste from a fixed register used elsewhere in the document*
>
>   ```
>   widget.snog()‸
>   ```
> - <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>a␣</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>b~</kbd><kbd>hx</kbd> — *paste the first arg, and capitalize*
>
>   ```
>   widget‸Foo.snog()
>   ```
> - <kbd>2w~</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>"zP</kbd> — *capitalize existing word, then paste the first arg again*
>
>   ```
>   widgetFoo.fo‸oSnog()
>   ```
> - <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> — *move to the last position, enter insert-mode, and end the macro*
>
>   ```
>   widgetFoo.fooSnog(‸)
>   ```
>
> After finishing the first instance with `bar`, we can now use it several times:
>
> - <kbd>o</kbd>baz<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> — *set up our first ‘argument’,*
>
>   ```
>   widgetFoo.fooSnog(bar)
>   ‸baz
>   ```
> - <kbd>@q</kbd>quux<kbd>Esc</kbd> — *invoke the macro, and finish with the second one*
>
>   ```
>   widgetFoo.fooSnog(bar)
>   widgetBaz.bazSnog(quux‸)
>   ```
> - <kbd>o</kbd>corge<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>@@</kbd>grault<kbd>Esc</kbd> — *repeat a third time*
>
>   ```
>   widgetFoo.fooSnog(bar)
>   widgetBaz.bazSnog(quux)
>   widgetCorge.corgeSnog(grault‸)
>   ```
> - <kbd>o</kbd>garply<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>@@</kbd>waldo<kbd>Esc</kbd> — *… and so on*
>
>   ```
>   widgetFoo.fooSnog(bar)
>   widgetBaz.bazSnog(quux)
>   widgetCorge.corgeSnog(grault)
>   widgetGarply.garplySnog(waldo‸)
>   ```

Of course, it looks laborious, typed out in such a long fashion — but it's surprisingly few key-strokes in practice, and very easy to train into your fingers.

---

**tl;dr**: type the first argument; enter macro-recording *before* deleting it into a register; manipulate your text as desired; then *leave vim in insert-mode* at the position of the second argument with <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate a code, which is the case, the best way for this is to use [vim snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets). You can configure snippet to put cursor where you need when you [tab].